# inflation rate is calculated wrong when using a for loop, i have provided two examples

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

All the following code is written by Abdulmalik Abougarboa

```
while True:
    try:
        year = int(input('Please enter the year that you want to calculate the personal interest rate for: ')) 
        expenditureCategories = int(input('Please enter the number of expenditure categories: ')) 
        break 
    except:
        print('\nerror ~ please insure you have entered a valid integer') 

if expenditureCategories == 1:
    expensesPre1 = int(input('Please enter expenses for previous year: ')) 
    expensesinterest1 = int(input('Please enter expenses for year of interest: ')) 
    
    current = (expensesinterest1) 
    pre = (expensesPre1) 

    infRate = ((current - pre)/ current)*100 
    print (f'Personal inflation for {year} is {infRate}%')
```

instead of repeating the code over and over, I created a for loop to handle that

```
while True:
    try:
        year = int(input('Please enter the year that you want to calculate the personal interest rate for: ')) 
        expenditureCategories = int(input('Please enter the number of expenditure categories: ')) 
        break 
    except:
        print('\nerror ~ please insure you have entered a valid integer') 

for i in range(expenditureCategories): 
    while True: 
        try:
            expensesPre = int(input('Please enter expenses for previous year: '))
            expensesinterest = int(input('Please enter expenses for year of interest: '))
    
            current = (expensesinterest) 
            pre = (expensesPre) 

            infRate = ((current - pre)/ current)*100 
            break 
        except:
            print('\nerror ~ please ensure you have entered a valid integer')

print (f'Personal inflation for {year} is {infRate}%')
```

if you run the two codes and input the following

Please enter the year that you want to calculate the personal interest rate for: 2022
Please enter the number of expenditure categories: 2
Please enter expenses for previous year: 100
Please enter expenses for year of interest: 100
Please enter expenses for previous year: 200
Please enter expenses for year of interest: 300

you get two different answers, the first one is correct, how can I make the for loop give me the same answer, thx.

Comment: You're only outputting the inflation rate at the end, for the final expenditure category. Is that your intention, or do you want it printed for every category?

Comment: I have other code that handles the rest like the what type of inflation it is, for now, my issue is calculating the infRate, and how when I input the following I get two outputs, the first one gives me 25.0 which is correct and the loop gives me 33.33333 which is wrong, so how can i get the for loop to gives te same answer as the other one?

Comment: Can't reproduce. For 2 categories the first script doesn't output anything. The formula to calculate the infRate is the same in both scripts, so there is no way the output can be different unless there is something you're not showing us, or you made a mistake in copying & pasting the code.

Comment: yeah Im only showing you a small part, ig ill check everything else, I thought I did something wrong in the loop it self cuz im not that good with for loops.